# How can I use a Dependancy Injection pattern to share a service between two IHostBuilder instances in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, backgroundworker, grpc

**Here's the background:**

I have a work-in-progress application that connects to multiple feeds from different internal systems via different protocols (HTTP, SMB, NFS, MSSQL), parses some data and then produces a `Report` object for each feed. The application must run as a Windows Service.

The feeds will be polled periodically - different schedules for different feeds - and changes to them logged.

The latest `Report` object for a given `FeedId` will then be collected via a gRPC client on-demand. I will not be the author of the system that will consume my `Report` objects, but gRPC seems fine to me and happy to accommodate.

So far, I have written a class `Worker` that inherits from `BackgroundService` and does a fine job of populating a `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Report>` object. Looking in the debugger I can see everything as I expect, updating at the correct intervals and so on.

I am hosting that `Worker` code with the following, which works great as a Windows Service:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

**Here's where I am stuck:**

The next step is to expose, via gRPC, a method like `GetLatestReport(FeedId)`. I've managed to build one following some guides, and I can get it to return a test, hard-coded Protobuf representation of my `Report` object just fine.

...**but** I can't work out how to use the Dependency Injection pattern to allow the `ConcurrentDictionary` to be referenced inside my gRPC method. What is the right way to share between my `BackgroundService` code and my Kestrel instance hosting gRPC?

I'm sure I can bodge it with a Singleton that has a private constructor, but this seems to be going against the grain with .NET Core. I'm sure I'm missing something simple!

Thanks in advance to anyone able to offer my any insight!

Comment: do you mind sharing a minimal reproducible code sample?

Answer (score 0):

The ConcurrentDictionary should not be stored in the application, but rather in a storage outside the application. something such as redis would be enough. if then you want to cache it in the application you can use memory cache.

Using a distributed storage like this means the data can also be accessed by different applications.